# Error 500: $facebook->api('/xxxxx/feed', 'post', $data) PHP SDK 3.2.2

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK PHP 3.2.2 yet in a project in Codeigniter. My function $facebook->api() work perfectly with commands like this:

```
$user = $facebook->api('/me');
$facebook->api('/me/accounts');
```

But when I want to make a post with this sentence:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/xxxxxx/feed', 'post', $data);
```

previously define $data, my explorer give me Error 500, but when I google this command everyone says work fine. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: The http 500 code is an internal server error. You would not fix it yourself, but with help of Facebook support.

Comment: I use api function and it works fine with one parameter, but with tree it doesn't work. I was seeing the method in base_facebook.php and this method look like this: public function api(/* polymorphic */)

Comment: @Braiam: Yes, but that 500 likely occurs on his own server. (FB SDK would throw an exception, if something was wrong on FB’s side.)

Comment: Go check your server’s error log.

Comment: Most likely you did not catch possible exceptions the SDK throws properly.

Comment: @CBroe I don't have messages in reference to this problem. As I said before, I was seeing the method "public function api(/* polymorphic */)", and I don't know it /*polymorphic*/ affect or something else, because with one parameter works.

Comment: _Are_ you properly catching exceptions or not?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ and we'll take a look. Make sure to include as much detail as possible: your App ID, your URLs, the error you receive, screenshots etc.